# eclipse calling database error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to add word from the `insert.java` class to the database `translate.sql` in the assets folder, but when i click the button for `insert.java` in the emulator it keeps shutdown unexpectedly.

I already search and trying to resolve this but seems it keep coming.

So i need help to identify the error in the code or some misspelling name from the database or others..

this is the class for `insert.java`

```
package com.han;

import android.app.Activity;
//import android.app.AlertDialog;
//import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

        public class Insert extends Activity {
        public Button search, add, back;
        public EditText indo;
        public EditText tora;
        public Cursor mCursor;
        public DbHelper helper;
        public String insertkataindonesia, insertkatatora;
        public int id,temp_id;
        public SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert);

         helper = new DbHelper(this);
         db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
         mCursor = helper.getAll();
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
         add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
         back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
         indo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertBahasaIndonesia);
         tora = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertBahasaTora);
         add.setEnabled(false);

         search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick (View v){
         String result = "";
         insertkataindonesia = indo.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
         mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id,kata_indo, kata_tora FROM translate " + "WHERE kata_indo =   '"+insertkataindonesia+"' ORDER BY kata_indo",null);
         if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){
         result = mCursor.getString(2);
         for
        (;!mCursor.isAfterLast();mCursor.moveToNext()){
         result = mCursor.getString(2);
         }
         }
         if (result.equals("")){
         result = "";
         Toast.makeText(Insert.this,"Kata tidak ditemukan, silahkan tambahkan kata", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         add.setEnabled(true);
         }
         tora.setText(result);
         }});

         add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick (View v){
         insertkataindonesia = indo.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
         insertkatatora =   tora.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
         if (insertkatatora.equals("") && insertkataindonesia.equals("")){
         Toast.makeText(Insert.this,"Tidak ada kata untuk disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else if (insertkatatora.equals("")){
         Toast.makeText(Insert.this,"Tidak ada kata toraja untuk disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else if (insertkataindonesia.equals("")){
         Toast.makeText(Insert.this,"Tidak ada kata Indonesia untuk disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else if (id==-1){
         Toast.makeText(Insert.this,"Kata sudah ada di database, silahkan hapus dulu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else{
         helper.insertKey(insertkataindonesia, insertkatatora);
         Toast.makeText(Insert.this,"Kata telah disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         indo.setText("");
         tora.setText("");
         }

         }


         });

         back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick (View v){
         Intent menu = new Intent(Insert.this,
        MainActivity.class);
         menu.putExtra("pesan", "From Insert Menu");
         startActivity(menu);
         }

         });
    }
}
```

and this is the class for `dbhelper.java`

```
package com.han;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME="translate.sql";
        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        private static final int VERSION = 1;
        private static File DATABASE_FILE;
        private boolean mInvalidDatabaseFile = false;
        private boolean mIsUpgraded = false;
        private Context mContext;
        private int mOpenConnections = 0;
        private static DbHelper mInstance;

        synchronized static public DbHelper getInstance(Context context) {

            if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new
            DbHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
            }
            return mInstance;
            }
            public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
            this.mContext = context;
            SQLiteDatabase db = null;
            try {
            db = getReadableDatabase();
            if (db != null) {
            db.close();
            }
            DATABASE_FILE =
            context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
            if (mInvalidDatabaseFile) {
            copyDatabase();
            }
            if (mIsUpgraded) {
            doUpgrade();

            }
            }catch (SQLiteException e) {
            } finally {
            if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
            db.close();
            }
            }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            mInvalidDatabaseFile = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int old_version,
            int new_version) {
            mInvalidDatabaseFile = true;
            mIsUpgraded = true;
            }
            private void doUpgrade() {
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            mOpenConnections++;
            if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
            }
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized void close() {
            mOpenConnections--;
            if (mOpenConnections == 0) {
            super.close();
            }
            }

            private void copyDatabase() {
            AssetManager assetManager =
            mContext.getResources().getAssets();
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;

            try {
            in = assetManager.open(DATABASE_NAME);
            out = new FileOutputStream(DATABASE_FILE);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            } catch (IOException e) {

            } finally {
            if (in != null) {

            try {
            in.close();
            } catch
            (IOException e) {}
            }

            if (out != null) {
            try {
            out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
            }

            setDatabaseVersion();
            mInvalidDatabaseFile = false;
            }

            private void setDatabaseVersion() {
            SQLiteDatabase db = null;
            try {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_FILE.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA user_version = " + VERSION);
            } catch (SQLiteException e ) {
            } finally {
            if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
            db.close();
            }
            }
            }

            public Cursor getAll (){
            return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, kata_indo, kata_tora from translate ORDER BY _id ASC",null));
            }

            public void insertKey(String indo, String tora){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("kata_indo", indo);
            cv.put("kata_tora", tora);
            getWritableDatabase().insert("translate","kata_indo", cv);
            }

            public void delete(long id){
            getWritableDatabase().delete("translate", KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);
        }
}
```

and here is the `logcat`

```
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.han/com.han.Insert}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: translate: , while compiling: SELECT _id, kata_indo, kata_tora from translate ORDER BY _id ASC
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: translate: , while compiling: SELECT _id, kata_indo, kata_tora from translate ORDER BY _id ASC
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.han.DbHelper.getAll(DbHelper.java:149)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.han.Insert.onCreate(Insert.java:31)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-18 00:16:38.489: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This error: `no such table: translate`, when you are SURE that the table's name and the request are written properly, typically means that you are working on an empty DB or that a table is missing because the creation of this one failed for some reasons.

For example I'm sure that there is the first access you make to the database right for this table? If you select something you will see that you have no table or data.

This error come from an error while creating the db. Basically what most of the apps are doing is creating an empty db in the device and then copying the content of the one provided with the app, in your `asset` folder, to the empty one. However if there is an error in the process the copy is cancelled and your database remains empty. If you create all the db programmatically it should mean that the table creation failed.

Try to `Select *` on your db to see if there is content or not, then check your db creation process. You'll probably find out that one of your tables  is missing, or that the creation of the db failed.